# Azure Devops Organization not showing up after moving to a different AAD

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I have a user in an Azure Active Directory managed by my company. For evaluation purposes I've created an organization in Azure Devops with a couple projects. I've also set up a Container Registry on Azure with the same user. Now I realized my user doesn't have sufficient permissions in the AAD to create applications, which prevented me from setting up a service connection for the ACR in Devops.

I then created 2 new AADs (first with the same user, then with a different one) and moved the Devops organization to those AADs. However, the organization never showed up on the organization list no matter what AAD I selected.

Additional, while I could access the organization via its URL, I sometimes struggled with SSH authentication when accessing the Git repositories.

Did I do anything wrong? Did I miss out anything?

Comment: How did you switch your organization connection from one Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) to another? Please follow this article to change the AAD connection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/change-azure-ad-connection?view=azure-devops.

Comment: Are you able to see that DevOps organization in [profile page](https://aex.dev.azure.com/me)?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT no it didn't show up there. I could only access it via URL.

Comment: In profile page, you could switch AAD under account. Are you able to switch to other AAD or microsoft account? You may provide the screenshot here.

Answer (score 1):

After changing the AAD connection, you need to ask each user in the organization to complete the following tasks:

1. Clear the cache for the Git Credential Manager if you use Visual Studio or the Git command-line tool. Delete the `%LocalAppData%\GitCredentialManager\tenant.cache` file on each client machine.
2. Regenerate new personal access tokens.
3. Request that SSH keys be manually cleared by Support, and then recreate SSH keys.
4. Rename your Microsoft account to a different email that doesn't conflict with your Azure AD identity. Doing so ensures that you won't be prompted to choose between accounts.
5. Adjust your Visual Studio subscription if the UPN used inside your Azure DevOps Services organization has changed.

Detailed information, you may refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/change-azure-ad-connection?view=azure-devops#inform-users-of-the-completed-change

Comment: I decided to set up the organization from scratch again. I'm just evaluating Devops as a potential candidate for our devops environment. I might need to move it back at some point, then I will follow those steps. Thanks anyway.